# Drag Force on a cylinder with its long axis aligned with the flow

Tags: drag, flow

yesterday I started looking into equations that link a cylinders diameter $r$ and length $L$ to the force experienced in a highly viscous medium ($Re<<1$).

I found the onseen-approximation but it seems like this equation is only valid for a a cylinder whose axis is perpendicular to the flow.

Does there exist an approximation for the drag force on a cylinder whose long axis is in **parallel** with the flow (constant velocity)?

Thanks,
Max

edit: What would change if the cylinder is hollow for $r<r'$?

Comment: Can one make the approximation that $L \gg r$?  Do you want a careful treatment of what happens around the ends of the cylinder?

Comment: I would like to look at both cases $L\gg r$ and $L\ll r$. What do you mean by careful treatment?

Comment: I'm trying to get a better sense of your boundary conditions.  What is the fluid doing far from the cylinder?  Are you interested in the details of what happens when the fluid passes around the corners at the top and bottom of the cylinder?

Comment: the fluid moves at constant velocity if far away from the cylinder. Does it help to assume smooth corners? It is not important what the fluid does there.